# How to create a portlet URL in JSF-Portlet

Tags: java, portlet, jsf-1.2, jsr286

The goal is to create a URL to the Portlet with this code:

```
ExternalContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
RenderResponse response = (RenderResponse)ctx.getResponse();
PortletURL portletUrl = response.createRenderURL();
String url = portletUrl .toString();
```

But if I call this in a backing bean's JSF-actionListener method, I get a `ClassCastException` because `ctx.getResponse()` gives me an `javax.portlet.ActionResponse` instead.

I know that a `RenderResponse` is accessible from the `doView` method in the Portlet class. But how can I access it in my backing bean?

Comment: If you're in the portlet, why redirect to the same place? Also, what portlet container are you writing to?

Comment: I'd like to put the link into an email that leads the user to the portlet. I'm using WebSphere Portal 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following approach now, which causes some (very little) workload overhead, but works well:

- Grab the `RenderResponse` in the `doView` method
- Use `PortletURL portletUrl = response.createRenderURL();` and store this object in the portlet session (with every request, I know).
- In your action listener method, retrieve the `PortletURL` object, append neccessary parameters and render the URL for whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to put link into an email that leads the user to the portlet. I'm using WebSphere Portal 6.1.

The render URL is not normally available at that point in the portlet lifecycle.

1. Consider using the [URL mapping features](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v6101/admin/adpltflt_sync.html)
2. Consider using a servlet with the [URL engine service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0612_behl/0612_behl.html) to perform a redirect

In both these cases, you don't need the huge encoded URL usually generated by Portal; you use something like `http://host/foo/bar` as your entry point.

*I've used the second approach in production. Unique names are added to the target pages and portlet instances for easy lookup. These are added to the page configuration via XMLAccess scripts - they are not available via the admin user interface in version 6.1.*

Comment: I knew the XMLAccess approach and used it some time, as well as using a specific redirecting servlet, but I was looking for a more "straight forward" solution.
I documented my final approach in my answer.
But nonetheless - thank you!

Comment: You said "they are not available via the admin user interface in version 6.1" - is there something new in 7.0?